# c - does waitpid() and co detect child termination only when all children are terminated?

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

I am writing this question with a bit of a confusion as i feel that I'm missing some point (that's why I am writing it, after all).

So i've been studying how multiple processes access a single file. I have a basic code that makes `fork` two times - both children `fprintf` into the same file, the main difference is that one of them `sleep`s and does much more `fprintf`s. Child `exit`s when all `fprinf`s are done. At the same time the parent `waitpid`s, and every time a child terminates it `fprintf`s into the same file.

What I wanted to see is 1) child process that had more `fprintf`s and `sleep` being terminated later then the other child (i think difference in running time should kinda provide a good probability that that would happen) - and that happens; 2) to see first `fprintf` of a parent process somewhere in the middle of the file as (how i thought!) the first child should be `waitpid`ed way before the second one is terminated - that is not what happened.

What happens every time is that both `fprintf`s are yielded into the file by the parent file at the very end of the file, just like the parent waited until both children are terminated and only then `waitpid`ed them.

Exchanging `waitpid` with `wait` obviously produced the same result.

I have several guesses:

1. The second child terminates faster then the parent have time to `waitpid` the first one and `fprintf` into the file.
2. The OS doesn't have time to send `SIGCHILD` to the parent before the second child terminates.
3. This is how `waitpid` works, like maybe signals are queued? (but i haven't found any specification of such functionality).

**Could somebody please explain why I am not getting the message about first child terminating in the middle of the file, but do get it at the end?**

---

*The code of the program:*

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <errno.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>
  
  #define N 1000000
  #define SLEEP_TIME 20
  
  int main(void)
  {
      FILE *fd1 = fopen("test.txt", "w");
      pid_t pid1, pid2, cpid;
      int wstatus;
  
      pid1 = fork();
      if(0 == pid1) {
          for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
              fprintf(fd1, "child1 %d %d\n", getpid(), i);
          }
          sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
          for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
              fprintf(fd1, "child1a %d %d\n", getpid(), i);
          }
          sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
          fclose(fd1);
          exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      } 
      else if(-1 == pid1) {
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      
      pid2 = fork();
      if(0 == pid2) { 
          for(int i = 0; i < N/2; ++i) {
              fprintf(fd1, "child2 %d %d\n", getpid(), i);
          }
          fclose(fd1);
          exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      } 
      else if(-1 == pid2) {
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      
      while(((cpid = wait(&wstatus)) != -1)) {
      //while(((cpid = waitpid(-1, &wstatus, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED)) != -1))               if(WIFEXITED(wstatus))
              fprintf(fd1, "child %d exited with status %d\n", cpid, wstatus);
      }        
      if(errno == ECHILD) { 
          fprintf(fd1, "All children are waited for!\n");
      }
      else {
          perror("waitpid");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      fclose(fd1);
      
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
```

*The last lines of the resulting file:*

```
2499998 child1a 7359 999997
2499999 child1a 7359 999998
2500000 child1a 7359 999999
2500001 child 7360 exited with status 0 //I wanted this one to be in the middle of the file!
2500002 child 7359 exited with status 0
2500003 All children are waited for!
```

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in your [mcve], that makes it harder for us to try it out and to replicate and debug your problem. If you want to mark out a special line in the source, then add a comment on that line, and mention it in the main body of the question.

Comment: As for your problem, the `wait` family of functions typically goes down to the kernel itself, and doesn't rely on user-space signals. The kernel have all the information about the processes, running, sleeping, waiting, and exited but not reaped.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, got it, thanks, enumeration deleted .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, waitpid does return each time a child exits.  The problem is that your test is flawed.

On Unix, when you access regular files with stdio functions such as `fprintf`, by default they are [fully buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176636/can-someone-please-explain-how-stdio-buffering-works).  This is desirable when only one process is writing to the file, as it reduces system call overhead, but can be undesirable when timing is important or when trying to synchronize with other processes.

So `waitpid` is in fact returning immediately after child2 exits, and `fprintf` is being called at that time, but it doesn't write its message into the the file immediately; rather, it remains buffered in the parent's memory.  It will only be written out when the buffer fills up (doesn't happen in the parent, it's usually many KB), or when you call `fflush` (you don't), or when the file is closed (including on process exit).  So both messages are written out together when you call `fclose(fd1)` in the parent, at which point both children have already exited.

For a test that better illustrates what's happening, disable buffering on this file by calling something like `setvbuf(fd1, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` immediately after opening the file.  Then you should see the "child2 exited" message in the middle of the file, as you expect.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, now it all makes sence.