# Is open() cross-platform in C?

Tags: c, file, cross-platform

Title, basically. Is [`open()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open) cross platform? I personally like the flags combined with `|` better than a string, so can I just use `open()` instead? Will it work anywhere `fopen()` will?

Comment: Windows emulates it.

Comment: Linux has `open`

Comment: If you're programming in C, and you want maximum portability, you want `fopen`.  That said, `open` is very popular and will work just about everywhere also; it's hard to imagine an environment you might actually find where `fopen` is available but `open` is not.

Comment: The real tradeoff here is not between file-opening modes as bitwise or-able flags versus strings, or even integer file descriptiors versus `FILE *`.  The real tradeoff is buffering.  If you know you don't want buffering, you want `open`.  But buffering is often a win, and if you use `open` and do I/O carelessly, you can end up with a program that's significantly inefficient.  For example, if you called `open` but you want `getchar`, and you simulate with with `read(fd, &c, 1)`, you end up with the most inefficient way of reading the file possible.

Comment: @SteveSummit When would I want or not want buffering?

Comment: @user15119853 Short answer: if you don't know, you want it.

Comment: Slightly longer answer: If you have a file descriptor that's not a file (perhaps a network socket), you often won't want buffering.  If you have a file that you're reading or writing in large, same-sized, filesystem-compatible blocks at a time -- 1024 bytes, 8192 bytes, etc -- and you have high-performance needs, you might not want buffering.  Otherwise, if you're reading/writing small or random-size scraps of text -- a few characters here, a few characters there, or a random-length line at a time, or anything like that -- you probably want buffering.

Comment: @SteveSummit So I know when or not I'd want buffering, but what does buffering actually do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write a tutorial just now, but try googling "[what does stdio buffering do?](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=QjUbYPyeHaLi5NoP_Na5yAI&q=what+does+stdio+buffering+do%3F)"  (One answer is [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176636/can-someone-please-explain-how-stdio-buffering-works).)

Comment: @SteveSummit Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` is part of the [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) specification, so it will work in any environment that implements this. This includes all modern flavors of Unix (POSIX is derived from Unix) as well as Windows. So you should be able to use it in any platform you're likely to encounter that also provides a hosted C implementation (so not a microcontroller, but it probably won't have `fopen()`, either).

If you want a `FILE *` that you can then use with all the other `stdio` functions (e.g. `fprintf()`) you can use `fdopen()` to get this from the FD returned by `open()`.