# How do i use scanf in C on Vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Im currently learning c, and I downloaded all necessary files for c to work on Vscode, if i run a code that doesnt have scanf, it runs normally, however, when I run a code that  has scanf in it, it simply says "Running"

[These are the extentions I downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrZhG.png)

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Insert number");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d",num);
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile and run, it says this:

[Running] cd "c:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Programação\C" && gcc Exemplo.c -o Exemplo && "c:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Programação\C"Exemplo

but nothing happens.
Can someone help me?

Comment: C stdio is [buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176636/can-someone-please-explain-how-stdio-buffering-works). Add `\n` to your printfs, or flush or disable the buffer.

Comment: ... and that has nothing in particular to do with VSCode.

Comment: Enter a number and hit return.  You'll see information.  End your last `printf()` format string with a newline — indeed, make most `printf()` format strings end with a newline.

Comment: Apart from you should always check the return value of `scanf` for the case that no number could be scanned at all (-> invalid input) – though this doesn't catch all possible input errors. I'd rather fetch entire input *lines* (`fgets`) and apply `sscanf` to the buffer read. Makes overall input handling (including error handling!) simpler.

Comment: @Gereon: 7.21.1/3: "Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, ***or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment.***"  There should be no need to explicitly flush the stream.

Comment: Buffering alone is not the issue here. The input and output streams should not be fully buffered unless the program can determine they do not refer to an interactive device. And, if they are line buffered, standard output (from `printf`) should be automatically flushed when input is solicited (`scanf` starts). There is something else in VS Code or OP’s configuration that is interfering with this, such as redirecting output to a pipe or file. I think we have seen that before on Stack Overflow but do not have a duplicate at hand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger of course it does. This doesn't happen in any human-friendly environment. "The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.19.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for input."  Not ensuring this is legal, but immoral.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, of course "it" **does not** -- where the "it" I'm talking about is the contents of Gereon's comment, observing that C stdio is buffered, and that the prompt string the OP prints is short and contains no newline.  None of that has anything to do with VSCode.  If adding a newline at the end of the prompt is not sufficient to resolve the issue then *that* would have something to do with VSCode, but it would also be a different issue.

Comment: @JohnBode good point, but if it resolves the problem and copes with a non-conforming execution environment does no harm?  I have frequently encountered non-hosted embedded systems environments that behave like this, so would do that habitually.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But of course it does --- the advised action "Add \n to your printfs, or flush or disable the buffer" is sufficient anywhere, but only *necessary* if you are in a hostile environment such as vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the code from the IDE (such as picking `Start Debugging` or `Start Without Debugging`), open a terminal (either within VSCode or a cmd shell), navigate to the directory where the code was built, and run the program from the command line:

```
> cd c:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Programação\C
> Exemplo
```

or just

```
> c:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Programação\C\Exemplo
```

I just played with it in VSCode on my Mac and got the same behavior -- it looks like there's an issue when trying to run an interactive C program from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` is likely not the issue here.  The problem is more likely that the VSCode stdout redirection is such that the stdout stream is not flushed as it should be when `scanf()` is called so the `printf()` prompt text is not output, pending a newline or a `fflush()`.

This is probably peculiar to the execution environment provided by VSCode, but I have seen this in other IDEs and non-hosted embedded systems. You can work around it by explicitly flushing stdout. Whilst that should not be necessary, but does no harm.

```c
printf("Insert number: ");
fflush( stdout ) ;
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Comment: This does not explain the problem. C 2018 7.21.3 7 says “… As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.” Since the streams are presented to the user, they cannot be determined not to refer to an interactive device and therefore should not be fully buffered…

Comment: … The alternatives are unbuffered (which should show the `printf` output immediately) or line buffered (which should show the `printf` output when the `scanf` starts per 7.21.3 3, “… Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment … or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment.”). So something in OP’s environment interfered with proper operation of the streams.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. I am a bit lost now.  Do your comments apply to my answer _before_ I edited it (which I did following your comment against the question),  or as it is now?

Comment: @EricPostpischil "Being presented to the user" is not the same thing as "being attached to an interactive device". What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.